# Configure Magento CE 2.3.2 message queue to use db instead of amqp

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2, magento-cron

I've just recently upgraded from **M2.2.8 to M2.3.2** and now I'm getting errors in **system.log** every minute or so that say.

*main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp []*

I have read through similar questions on here but I can't find an answer to the problem.

I can see the job is running in a cron group by using the command "**php bin/magento queue:consumers:list**" but there's nothing configured in env,PHP as I don't use **RabbitMQ**

If I trigger a bulk product edit in the admin, I get a message added to the queued alert and when I go to **system->bulk actions** I can see that the job completed. That indicates to me that for some actions, it is using the DB for the message queue, not amqp.

However, the job "**async.operations.all**" which I think is the Bulk Cleanup job in the cron seems to only want to use the amqp connection and not the DB.
That job, I think, is in

**vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/Cron/BulkCleanup.php**

but there isn't anywhere in that that sets it to amqp.

I've had just found that it's mentioned in

**vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations**

amqp is mentioned in 2 files

**module-asynchronous-operations\etc\di.xml (Line 90)**

**module-asynchronous-operations\Model\ConfigInterface.php (Line 28)**

but changing those to db didn't fix it.

I'm simply trying to stop system.log filling up all the time and use the DB message queue for all messages but I'm struggling with it and would appreciate your help everyone.